# :hover to change other element, but it triggers from the target as well

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a problem. I have made a targeted hover with .trigger:hover .target {} .. my problem though is that it triggers from the .target as well..

```css
.trigger {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #444;
  position: relative;
}

.target {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #111;
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}

.trigger:hover .target {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="trigger">
  <div class="target"></div>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Ls4ejw60/

how does one prevent this? .. i have seen it being done with this method of .trigger:hover .target {}, but i haven't figured out how to prevent it from triggering off the target.

Comment: `pointer-events:none`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the `.target`:

```css
.trigger {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #444;
  position: relative;
}

.target {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #111;
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.trigger:hover .target {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="trigger">
  <div class="target"></div>
</div>
```

Another option is to move it out of the `.trigger`, and use the [adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), but then you'll have to define it's size explicitly, and position it beside the trigger in another way (I've used `display: flex;` on the body):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.trigger, .target {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.trigger {
  background: #444;
  position: relative;
}

.target {
  background: #111;
}

.trigger:hover + .target {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="trigger"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that the pointer-events property is exactly the solution i needed !